# How do I check a string for a range of strings in C?

Tags: c, string, if-statement

I have to create a Solitaire Program in C. I have the data structure set up but I have a question about comparing strings.

The user input has to look like "move [colour] [value] to [stack]".

Now my plan was to use `strncmp` to see if the string contained **"move"** **"color"**, etc. But with **"value"** I have a range of 13 acceptable inputs (Ace to King), which means I would need 13 different if-statements. Is there a more elegant way to check which "value" the input holds?

Examples: "move red 4 to 3" 
or 
"move black K to 6"

After I determined what the user specified, I have to find the given card in 7 double linked lists and move it to another list as specified by the user.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of the ace to king field?

Comment: One solution is an array, e.g. `char *values[] = { "Ace", "Two", ... , "King" };`. Then you can use a `for` loop to compare each string in the array with the user's string.

Comment: @AlexW I would have picked char, as the entire imput is a char[]

Comment: It would help a lot if you added a few examples of the user input to the question.

Comment: It seems that the values (ace, 2-10, jack, queen, king) are already distinct in the first character. So you could `switch` on the first character and then do a single `strcmp` per `case` to verify.

Comment: @user3386109 That's a good point, thanks. But I'd still need 13 ifs, right? Because if strncmp finds **five**, then I'd need to check at which point in the array strncmp was successful.

Comment: When you iterate over the array, you know the successful point by the index at which you found a match. Either use the index as the internal representation of that value (or something like `index + 1` so if your array starts with ace it gets the value `1`), or have an array of `struct` where each structure contains the string in one field and any associated data (such as the desired internal value) in other fields. The `struct` approach has an advantage in that it's easy to have aliases, e.g., "2", "two", "deuce" could all match the same value.

Comment: The output of the loop would be an index into the array. So a number from 0 to 12. How to use that number is outside the scope of the question, since you haven't given us enough context to know what the next step is. Strings are hard to deal with in C, so converting string input into numbers is typically the first step in a C program. Then you need to decide what to do with the numbers.

Comment: I suppose, you can sort the list of your e.g. string values, then you could use the bsearch() function. You'll get a O(log n) instead of your O(n), with 13 there are a maximum of 4 compares. When you have 10000 strings, you get 14 cpmpares as maximum.

Comment: The overhead of a `O(log n)` solution is *far, far, far* greater than a couple of `BEQ`s...

Comment: @Arkku Thank you, that helped. One question though: When checking for the value I check for "A" and "a". If I pass the whole string to my function, it catches the "a" in "black". How can I combat this?

Comment: @MaximilianWolf You should not be looking at the colour part at all when you are parsing/validating value. Tokenize the string first, e.g., with `strtok` or `sscanf`. Then validate each field separately. And if you are using the `strchr` part of my answer, you would not be looking for each valid value in the input, but rather the input in the set of valid values. (For uppercase/lowercase support in the `strchr` solution you can either convert case of the input first or match against both cases and then disambiguate.)

Comment: @MaximilianWolf …or you could just go to the original suggestion in my comment, and `switch` on the first character. Simply let `case 'a'` fall through to `case 'A'`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input for value is a single character, you can simply check that the character exists in the list of valid characters:

```
const char valid_values[] = "A23456789TJQK";
if (strchr(valid_values, input_value[0])) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

You can even use the character itself internally as-is as the representation of the value (since it is both unique and optimally small at 1 `char`). Or you can convert to the numerical value by taking the index (such as by subtracting `valid_values` from the non-`NULL` return value of `strchr`) and adding `1`.

If you wish to allow multiple alternatives (such as "A", "ace" or "two", "2", "deuce"), a simple alternative is to make an array of string-value pairs and iterate over them until a match is found or the end is reached:

```
struct value_string {
    const char *string;
    int value;
};
const struct value_string valid_values[] = {
    { .string = "A", .value = 1 },
    { .string = "ace", .value = 1 },
    { .string = "2", .value = 2 },
    { .string = "two", .value = 2 },
    // …
    { .string = "K", .value = 13 },
    { .string = NULL, .value = 0 } // terminator
};

int card_value = 0;
for (const struct value_string *p = valid_values; p->string; ++p) {
    if (strcmp(p->string, input_value) == 0) {
        // found match
        card_value = p->value;
        break;
    }
}
if (card_value) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

The benefits of this kind of a solution are in the clarity and expandability of code, rather than on improving performance or reducing the total number of lines. For the best performance I would expect a look-up table (or simply a `switch`) by first character and then manual character-by-character validation (of the remaining possibilities, only) to be hard to beat.